# Getting error in using Tuple in CPLEX OPL to read data from a set in the tuple

Tags: cplex, opl

I have a tuple for reading a set of paths.

```
tuple Path {
int id;
string source;
string dest;
{string} pitblockSet;
{string} roadPoints; // not used
{string} dumpblockSet;
{string} others;
float dist;
};
{Path} Pbd= {} // a set read using into Pbd
```

There is another tuple blockType

```
tuple blockType {
    string id;
    int i;
    int j;
    int k;
 };
```

{blockType} PitBlocksType = ...;
This is read from excel..and the data looks like below

```
P1  1   1   2
P2  1   1   3
P3  1   1   4
P4  1   1   5
P5  1   1   6
P6  1   1   7
P7  1   1   8
P8  1   1   9
P9  1   1   10
P10 1   1   11
```

BlockBelow is defined as below.

```
{blockType} BlockBelow[b1 in PitBlocksType] =
     {b | b in PitBlocksType: b1.i == b.i -1 &&
                        (b1.k  == b.k ) &&
                         (b1.j  == b.j) };
```

I am using constraints such as the two below. But I am getting error. I want to have the sum of BlockBelow for all blocks in the pitblockSet as shown below. But I am making some mistake in accessing the pitblockSet in the tuple Pbd ( of type Path)

```
forall( i in Pbd.pitblockSet,  t in TimePeriods) { 
       // blockabove exposed Pbd:
        sum(j in BlockBelow[i]) schedulePit[j.id][t] * totalVolume[j.id] <= 
        (sum(j in BlockBelow[i],r in TimePeriods : r <= t,d in DumpBlocks)(Xbdt[j.id][d][r])  
        + sum(j in BlockBelow[i],r in TimePeriods : r <= t, s in Stockpiles)(Xbst[j.id][s][r]/density[j.id])
        +sum(j in BlockBelow[i],r in TimePeriods : r <= t, m in Plants)(Xbmt[j.id][m][r]/density[j.id]))  ;      
        }        



 forall(d in Pbd.dumpblockSet, t in TimePeriods) {   
  //DumpblocksBelow
  sum( b in PitBlocks,j in OnBelowDump[d],  r in TimePeriods: r<=t)(Xbdt[b][j.id][r]*SwellFactor)
 - scheduleDump[d.id][t]* sum(j in OnBelowDump[d])(dumpVolume[j.id]) >= 0;
   }
```

The error I get is : Expecting a tuple type, found {Path}.
Need suggestions please on how to access the pitblockSet  or dumpblockSet in Pbd

Answer (score 0):

The statement

```
forall( i in Pbd.pitblockSet,  t in TimePeriods)
```

looks wrong. According to your definition, `Pbd` is a *set* of paths, so it does not have a `pitblockSet` property. Only the *elements* in this set have this property.

I am not sure what youre trying to do here. If you want to have all paths that intersect a certain block type `B` you can use:

```
forall (p in Pbd : `B` in p.pitblockSet)
```

If you want a set with all block types you can form the union over all `p.pitblockSet` for all paths.

**EDIT** after you gave some clarification in the comments:

As far as I understand, your `blockType` is indexed by `id`. If that is true then I suggest to mark this as key:

```
tuple blockType {
  key string id;
  int i;
  int j;
  int k;
}
```

If you do so, then you can get the block types and block ids below each path as follows:

```
{blockType} BlockTypeBelowPath[p in Pbd] = union(b in p.pitblockSet) BlockBelow[<b>];
{string} BlockIDBelowPath[p in Pbd] = { b.id | b in BlockTypeBelowPath[p] };
execute {
  writeln("BlockTypeBelowPath: ", BlockTypeBelowPath);
  writeln("BlockIDBelowPath: ", BlockIDBelowPath);
}
```

Comment: Thank you Daniel for your response. Actually its part of a larger problem. pitBlockSet is a subset of a bigger set of blocks. Blocks Below exist for each block. I am trying to find that for all blocks in pitBlockSet the summation of these blocks over several variables. However blocksbleow has block Id and other items, where as pitBlockSet only has block Id. ..Sorry my understanding of OPL is limited. Could not get how to use the 'B'

Comment: I updated my answer. It would really help if you could give a fully worked out example: what is your input? what do you want to construct? how should the result look like? In particular the last point is not clear to me.

Comment: Thank you Daniel.                    I have tried your edited suggestion, may be I am not doing it right. I have {blockType} BlockTypeBelowPath[p in Pbd] = union(b in p.pitblockSet) BlockBelow[<b>];   and I get error on that line as Index out of bound for array "BlockBelow": <"">

Comment: That would mean that in some of the `pitblockSet` you have a value that does not exist in `BlockBelow`. Make sure that your data is consistent, maybe dump everything to screen to double-check. If you continue to have problems then maybe it is a good idea to start a new question (and close this one because I think the original question was ansered) in which you can show your current state of code.